# List of queries run

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I'm looking for a DMV query for SQL Server 2008 R2 which shows me all queries (full history) run by a specific user.

I have this code for now:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) st
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
```

but is it possible to join another DMV which allows me to filter results on login name?

Comment: Does [how to get History of queries executed with username in SQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135080/8783) help ? You wont be getting FULL history though - unless you have enabled some logging.

Comment: "I'm looking for a DMV query for SQL Server 2008 R2 which shows me all queries (full history) run by a specific user." - This doesn't exist out the box. You would need to use tracing, extended events or SQL Audit.

Answer (score -1):

LoginName and Hostname from Sys.sysprocesses

you've already got a cross apply to dm_exec_Sql_Text. so you've already got everything else you need.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would join `sys.sysprocesses` to the DMVs used in the question?

Comment: `select sp.loginname
FROM sys.sysprocesses sp
CROSS APPLY Sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sp.sql_handle) `

Comment: And how does this get a full history?

Comment: DMV's won't give you a full history anyways unless you log their output longitudinally.

You'd have to build a job to do that. and you'd have to have it in place prior to wanting to answer the question of What did Steve run last Tuesday?